# Opencart: Limit shipping on specific product to one Country

Tags: opencart

Certain products on my site can only be shipped USA wide and not to Canada (As is allowed by the Geozones I created). I need to somehow implement this on my site (prevent users from shipping certain items to Canada.) I am not well versed in coding and would prefer changing a few lines of code or ideally using an extension to achieve this.

Thank you

EDIT: I have no problem paying for an extension if one exists to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, welcome to the **StackOverflow!**

The truth is that products are not allowed/restricted per Geo Zones... Geo Zones serve for Taxes calculation, not for shipping restrictions. Or the zones could be used to allow/restrict certain payment/shipping types based on the client's address.

But again, within a default OC it is not possible to restrict product shipping to a certain countries.

Anyway, this could be implemented but I doubt anybody here would do this for free and share his/her code as it is kinda huge modification... Also this has some trickiness:

- either all of the clients would have to be registered and logged in prior to adding products into the cart (to check their address against the product's geo zone)
- or the modification would have to implemented in the **checkout** process that couldn't be completed unless certain products are removed from the cart - which could be very unconvenient and/or rude against customers...
- or You may want to implement it both ways while when customer is logged in he even won't see the products he cannot order...

You may find me always repeating myself, but I have to remind that this is kinda huge modification that I doubt anybody will do for free. But it could be implemented as vQmod extension...

Comment: I am willing to pay for it if it exists as a vQmod extension

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to create product option with select country and city you can use chain option module for it then implement the option for the product you want to limit shipping and make sure the "Required" in the product option set to "YES" so when the customer want to add the product he must select the country and the city where he want the shipping to be send if is city not there then he will not be able to add this product to is cart. 
Hope this will give you an option other then file modification.